# R: How to rename columns with row value dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, rename

I am trying to rename the columns of my data frame with the row values. I have the following:

```
                FIRM TIME          V_Ri
1   A EAGLE 14DEC1994  740 -0.0005039933
2   A EAGLE 14DEC1994  741  0.0000000000
3   A EAGLE 14DEC1994  742  0.0238607800
4   A EAGLE 14DEC1994  743 -0.0125612300
5   A EAGLE 14DEC1994  744 -0.0134325100
```

And I would like to obtain:

```
                 FIRM            740          741    etc.
1   A EAGLE 14DEC1994  -0.0005039933 0.0000000000
```

I have tried by transposing, but couldn't reach the desired result. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R one-liner (Thanks @Ben Norris for the dataset):

```
spread_df <- as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(V_Ri ~ FIRM+TIME, df))
```

If you want to reset the index column and push the row.names back to a FIRM vector:

```
data.frame(FIRM = row.names(spread_df), spread_df, row.names = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem for `pivot_wider()` from the `tidyr` package.

If your data is in a data.frame called `df`, do the following:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "TIME", values_from = "V_Ri")

# A tibble: 1 x 6
  FIRM                  `740` `741`  `742`   `743`   `744`
  <chr>                 <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A EAGLE 14DEC1994 -0.000504     0 0.0239 -0.0126 -0.0134
```

Note that the column names have back ticks around the numbers. Names of objects, including column names, are not typically allowed to start with numerals. The back tick encapsulates nonstandard names.

Sample data used:

```
df <- structure(list(FIRM = c("A EAGLE 14DEC1994", "A EAGLE 14DEC1994", 
                              "A EAGLE 14DEC1994", "A EAGLE 14DEC1994", 
                              "A EAGLE 14DEC1994"), 
                     TIME = c(740, 741, 742, 743, 744), 
                     V_Ri = c(-0.0005039933, 0, 0.02386078, -0.01256123, 
                              -0.01343251)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```